# VueJs2 HTTP Get Request from JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js

I am working on retrieving data from a JSON API by VueJs 2. I can retrieve data from the URL using the following code.

My component is showGet. I am using jsonplaceholder data and it's working fine.
But when I give my desired API (https://news.ontario.ca/newsroom/en.json) it does not work. This API works nicely in Postman. In my browser it's showing JSON data.
But whenever I put my URL in Vue HTTP get request it does not work.

It's not even showing in `console.log(data)`.

```
<script>

export default {

  data(){
    return{
     blogs:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{

  },
  created(){
      this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
         this.blogs= data.body.slice(0,10);
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

My App.vue code is below:

```
<script>

import showGet from './components/showGet'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    showGet
  },
  data(){
    return{

    }
  },
  methods:{

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you need to send on the request something equivalent to withCredentials: true

Comment: This problem is related to Cross-origin Requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see any issues in your code

maybe you are not including `vue-resource` (required to use `this.$http`)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      this.blogs = data.body.slice(0, 10);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="blog in blogs">
      {{ blog.id }} - {{ blog.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```